# How can I get data from database?

Tags: php, mysql, database

A guy did some php/database work for me a while back. He linked the pages to a menu (which had a separate function/table). I'm a little lost on how it's beneficial to link everything to a menu like that.

Here's the code I'm trying to figure out:

```
function writeContent($page){
$parentQ = "select * from cdi_content where page=\"$page\"";//query to obtain content for this page
$parentResult = mysql_query($parentQ);//run query
$link = mysql_fetch_assoc($parentResult);//result
echo $link['content'];//write content`
}
```

With `<?php writeContent("DDesign/index.php");?>` on the index.php page he created.

From what I understand it runs through the menu function, but I'm just trying to get it to print what's in the "content" field in the database.

Comment: The code above opens a connection to the Database, gets all columns related to a given page, and then extracts the 'content' field from the result and then prints it. sounds like it does exactly what you want.

Comment: Yeah.. it was a palm/face error on my end.. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check how many number of rows are there in the query. Replace that piece if code with this.

```
function writeContent($page){
    $parentQ = "select * from cdi_content where page=\"$page\"";//query to obtain content for this page
    $parentResult = mysql_query($parentQ);//run query
    $total = mysql_num_rows($parentResult);

    if($total > 1) {

        while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($parentResult) {

            echo "Content: ".$row['content'] . "<br/>";
        }

    }else{

            $rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($parentResult);//result
            echo $rows['content'];//write content`

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
select * from cdi_content where page=\"$page\"
```

For

```
select content from cdi_content where page=\"$page\"
```

Or whatever is the field name

Answer (score -1):

To get the content of variable `$link`  use:

```
print_r($link);
```